# Fivetran vs Stitch Jira connector

Tags: etl, stitch, fivetran

From reading online it seems like Stitch is a direct comptetor to Fivetran. However, for data replication it seems like Fivetran does a lot of transformation beforehand before injecting the data. For example, splitting json columns into individual tables, column renaming to certain degree etc.

However, i do not see the same behaviour with Stitch.

Specifically talking about JIRA connector, Stitch is sending several tables as issues__fields__customfield_10016, and then each table has a lot of custom_fileds.

Whats the best way to ingest/comprehend this information.

Stitch support is absolute shocking